# ¿Cómo puedo salir de un sys.stdin.redline() despues de unos segundos?

Tags: python, while

Actualmente estoy leyendo un pdf417 de las cédulas de ciudadanía de mi país con la ayuda de un lector de códigos de barras, dicho lector es reconocido como un teclado en mi raspberry, necesito leer todo lo que me envía el lector, lo cual esta separado con "\n" y saber cuando terminó leer para seguir el programa, necesito saber si puedo saltarme esa linea después de unos segundo...

```
def read_decoder():
    global datos
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) > 0:
            print parts
            datos.append(parts)
```

Cómo dije antes, necesito que después de unos segundos de estar parado en:

```
line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

devuelva el **break** y se salte el **while True:**

Comment: Me suena más a que tengas la opción de usar eventos antes que tener ese `while true` nefasto. En programación por eventos estarías escuchando un evento o serie de eventos específicos y reaccionar en consecuencia. Hacer ese `break` que pretendes no siempre será una buena idea. Podrías usar alguna librería como [Events](https://pypi.org/project/Events/), aunque eso igual dependerá de lo que necesites hacer. Saludos

Comment: Las soluciones al problema del time-out no son portables en su mayorìa. Hay soluciones específicas para Linux y otras para Windows. Como dice Mauricio, es mejor cambiar de enfoque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece no haber soluciones que sean válidas para todos los ambientes (Linux, Windows, Mac).

Esta solución funciona para Linux, pero no para Windows. Tal vez alguien más ofrezca una alternativa para Windows.

```
import sys
from select import select

def input_timeout(msg, timeout):
    """ Pide un texto con timeout

    @param msg: Mensaje a desplegar.
    @param timeout: Timeout en segundos para esperar respuesta
    @return La respuesta, o None si se cumplio el timeout
    """
    print(msg)
    readables, writeables, exceptions = select([sys.stdin],[],[], timeout)
    return sys.stdin.readline() if len(readables) else None


respuesta = input_timeout("Ingrese", 5)
if respuesta:
    print(respuesta)
```

La función `select` recibe tres listas de socket o descriptores de archivos y retorna tres listas con aquellos sockets o descriptores que tienen algo que leer, están preparados para escribir o han sufrido alguna excepción. El cuarto parámetro es el timeout en segundos, si ninguno de los sockets ha cambiado.

La única lista que nos interesa es `readables`. Si tiene algún elemento, significa que se puede leer de `stdin`.

Si no hay nada que leer, la función `input_timeout` retorna `None`.